# How add data to a map

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore, flatmap

I use *google cloud firestore* and I have a map in the documents. I then want to push an updated map to the *database*.

The document looks like this:
[image]

My model for the document looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import Firestore

protocol  DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}


struct Exercise {
    var title: String
    var language: String
    var translated: String
    var uid: String
    var userId: String
    var dueDate: Int
    var lastOpen: Int
    var words: Array<Any>
    var sharedUsers: [String: Bool]

    var dictionary:[String:Any] {
        return [
            "title":title,
            "language":language,
            "translated":translated,
            "uid":uid,
            "userId":userId,
            "dueDate":dueDate,
            "lastOpen":lastOpen,
            "words":words,
            "sharedUsers":sharedUsers
        ]
    }
}

extension Exercise : DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let title = dictionary["title"] as? String,
            let language = dictionary["language"] as? String,
            let translated = dictionary["translated"] as? String,
            let uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String,
            let userId = dictionary["userId"] as? String,
            let dueDate = dictionary["dueDate"] as? Int,
            let lastOpen = dictionary["lastOpen"] as? Int,
            let words = dictionary["words"] as? Array<Any>,
            let sharedUsers = dictionary["sharedUsers"] as? [String: Bool]

        else {return nil}

        self.init(title: title, language: language, translated: translated, uid: uid, userId: userId, dueDate: dueDate, lastOpen: lastOpen, words: words, sharedUsers: sharedUsers)
    }
}
```

So, how can I create an object that looks like this, *(String:Bool),* and put that in a map?

I hope I have provided enough information, otherwise feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, do you want to update sharedUsers field for example? If so, have a look: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen